# Two point correlator : Dispersion Relation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions

Does anybody has a reference or an advice on how to derive the following idendity?

\begin{equation}
\Pi(s) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{Im \Pi(s')}{s' - s} ds'
\end{equation}
where $\Pi(s)$ is the two point correlator.

I know its somehow connected with Cauchys theorem, but could not make any progress with that information.

Comment: Looks like Kramers-Kronig to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations

Comment: It is Kramers-Kronig, thanks a lot! @CuriousOne